# how to compile a ruby code on my vim-editor for very simple and easy way... or some trick

Tags: ruby, vim, compilation

I'm trying to learn VIM editor , and I'm going to test some small code

for ruby

here is question..

When I compile and launch my small ruby code,

1. Command-mode,

`:!ruby %`

2. Or Open another terminal,

`$ruby filename.rb`

I did ,

but.. its really stressful and I cannot focus....

Is there any magical things?? , 
config .vimrc file then make a hot-key 
or... make some script by rubyself...??

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? It's difficult to understand what you are doing and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:!!` to repeat the last `:!{cmd}`.

You can type `:!ruby %` once, and then run `:!!`, which can of course be mapped to a key like:

```
nnoremap <F8> :!!<CR>
```

Or to write and run it (saves typing `:w`):

```
nnoremap <F8> :w<CR>:!!<CR>
```

This is a flexible solution, since you can replace `:!ruby %` with anything else (e.g. `:!coffee -c %`, `:!python %`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

If your vim distribution has `ruby` support, can be confirmed using `vim --version |grep ruby`, Then

```
 nnoremap <F9> :rubyfile %<CR>
```

This is will be more faster as this does not invoke an external command using `!ruby` and hence no shell launch. More details at `:help ruby`.

Another way to complete the work irrespective of `ruby support`.
Your vim distribution will come with `$VIMRUNTIME/compiler/ruby.vim` for `compiler` setting. If so, you can set it `:compiler ruby` for ruby files in your vimrc.

This will allow you to just do `make` to accomplish what you are doing. But output looks somewhat clumsy. 
Hence, Having a some keybinding will help

```
nnoremap <f9> :make<CR> :copen<CR>
```

This will open a `quickfix` for error. You can just press <kbd>F9</kbd> or any other key that you have mapped.

You might also like to review quickfix commands at `:help quickfix`

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this to your `.vimrc`. It's not exactly sophisticated, but may be good enough for your needs:

```
" Run current file as Ruby program
nnoremap <C-r> :!ruby %<CR>
```

Comment: Not sure if `<C-r>` is a great example mapping, as it's already the commonly used `redo`... ;-)

Comment: Map it to something else then :)